# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined : Http

Tags: angular, http

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to pull data from a link that I have created using http but there seems to be an error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Am I doing anything wrong?

```js
this.configSerivce.getConfig().subscribe(data  => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

```html
export class ConfigService {
configUrl : "http://d1vse12sdoa01.ivu-ag.com:8080/daan-rest/services/line" ;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
  getConfig(){
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you use `toLowerCase`

Comment: The code that you provided doesn't include the toLowerCase string method. The problem is out

Comment: I didnt use any toLowerCase thats the problem

Comment: I manage to solve it by changing ':' to '=' , anyway thanks guys

Comment: the toLowerCase came from the url you are using for the xhr, so yes your httpclient couldn't use your url with a string type declaration only ( your ":" and not "=" )

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 return this.http.get(this.configUrl)
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    return response.json()
                })
                .catch((err: any) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
```